# How Do I Make a POST Request with Node.JS to Ghostbin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request, httprequest

I'm trying to send a POST request to [Ghostbin](https://ghostbin.com) via Node.JS and its `request` NPM module. Here's what my code looks like:

Attempt 1:

```
reqest.post({
   url: "https://ghostbin.com/paste/new",
   text: "test post"
}, function (err, res, body) {
   console.log(res)
})
```

Attempt 2:

```
reqest.post({
   url: "https://ghostbin.com/paste/new",
   text: "test post",
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Content-Length": 9
   }
}, function (err, res, body) {
   console.log(res)
})
```

Attempt 3:

```
reqest.post("https://ghostbin.com/paste/new", {form: {text: "test post"}}, function (err, res, body) {
   console.log(res)
})
```

All of these attempts ended up logging:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>\n<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /paste/new could not be found on this server.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at ghostbin.com Port 443</address>\n</body></html>
```

Is there something I'm missing regarding the `request` library, or with [the documentation of the Ghostbin API](https://ghostbin.com/paste/p3qcy)?

Comment: Take a look at the request [docs](https://github.com/request/request), seems like `text` is not an option.

Comment: @RolandStarke but thats what the Ghostbin docs ask for, and also I tried one more thing I just edited in and it also gave the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right but you need to pass data into `form` key(as you did in #3) and pass `user-agent` in header as mention in api

```
reqest.post({
   url: "https://ghostbin.com/paste/new",
   form: {
     text: "test post"
   },
   headers: {
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
   }
}, function (err, res, body) {
   console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: This seems to be working but how can I get it to log information such as the paste ID?

Comment: Grab `res.headers.location` to get the paste URL.

Answer (score 0):

this how i do it using request tested and working for me

```
var request = require('request'); 
var url= 'your link here';
var headers = { // add the browser sent header request data
'User-Agent':       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101      Firefox/48.0",
'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'    
}
// Configure the request
var options = {
url: url,
method: 'POST',
headers: headers,
form: {'user': 'value', 'pass': 'value'}
}
// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
console.log(body)
});
```

Comment: Same as what I said for Arif Khan's post